# grep regex match only if a line doesn't start by

Tags: regex, bash, grep, gnu

> i put a test file at the bottom of this post with a expected result

### What i want

---

I have some file in folder like that for example :

```sh
src
├── app
│   ├── app.controller.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── app.service.ts
│   └── interceptor
│       └── json-api.interceptor.ts
├── auth
│   ├── auth.controller.ts
│   ├── auth.module.ts
│   ├── auth.service.ts
│   ├── decorator
│   │   ├── auth-user.decorator.ts
│   │   ├── is-secret.decorator.ts
```

I want a script that retrieves my `jsdoc` into this file plus the name for the function concerned by the jsdoc and insert the result into a `.md` file.

The `jsdoc` start always in a new line by `/**` and end always in a new line by `*/`.

The line between the start & the end is always started by a `*` .

And after the end line of the jsdoc we have `@` or `[A-Za-z]`. I want to match this line only if the pattern is not equal to `@`.

Example :

```sh
/** << start
 *  << the line between
 */ << end
@ xxxxxx << possible negative value
function xxxxx << possible positive value
const xxxx << possible positive value
xxxxx << possible positive value
```

but i don't want to retrieve the following pattern :

```
/** something */
@ or xxxxxx
```

### My research

---

I started with the jsdoc :

```
grep -Pro "(\/\*\*$)|(^\s+\*\s.*)|(^\s+\*\/$)" test.txt
```

the result is ok :

```
➜ grep -Pro "(\/\*\*$)|(^\s+\*\s.*)|(^\s+\*\/$)" test.txt
/**
   * check if the user level is super admin
   * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
   */
/**
   * check if the user level is super admin
   * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
   */
/**
   * check if the user level is super admin
   * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
   */
```

Now i want to have the line after if this line not start by `@`, for that i have made this regex

```
((\s*)([^@]|\w)(.*))
```

but this not work at all.

If i use a negative lookahead `(\s*)(?![@])(.+)` the console tell me `event not found: [@])(.+)`.

I'm pretty lost, if you have any idea how to do that thanks. If you want more infos tell me.

### test file & expected result

---

```
➜ cat test.txt 
// case 1
  /**
   * check if the user level is super admin
   * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
   */
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'), LevelsGuard)
  @Levels(LevelEnum.superadmin)
  @Get('check/superadmin')
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  checkSuperAdminLevel(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

// case 2
  /**
   * check if the user level is super admin
   * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
   */
  @Get('check/superadmin')
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  checkSuperAdminLevel(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

// case 3
  /**
   * check if the user level is super admin
   * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
   */
  checkSuperAdminLevel(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

// case 4
  /** lorem ipsum */

// case 5
  lorem ipsum
```

the expected result

```
// case 1
/**
 * check if the user level is super admin
 * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
 */
checkSuperAdminLevel(): boolean {

// case 2
/**
 * check if the user level is super admin
 * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
 */
checkSuperAdminLevel(): boolean {

// case 3
/**
 * check if the user level is super admin
 * @returns {boolean} true if the user has the right to access super admin endpoints
 */
checkSuperAdminLevel(): boolean {

// case 4
nothing

// case 5
nothing
```

Comment: `set +H` to disable history expansion and not print `event not found` error, see `help set`

Comment: Try `grep -zroP '(?m)/\*\*$\n?|^\h+\*\h.*$\n?|^\h+\*/$\n?|(?<=\*/\n)(?:\h+@.*\n)*\K.+\n?' test.txt`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uryDMb/3).

Comment: This is pretty good @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for the link it allowed me to understand how you built it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a GNU `grep`, it is possible to achieve what you want extending your regex a bit more.

First, add `-z` option, it will allow slurping the file into a single string input (`grep` pattern will "see" line breaks).

Second, you need to make sure the `$` anchors are matching end of *lines*, not just the whole string, so you need the *multiline* modifier, `(?m)`.

Third, linebreaks need to be matched, too, to have line breaks in the output, thus, right at the end of each alternative, you need to put `\n?`, an optional newline.

Fourth, as this is a PCRE pattern, it will support `\h` construct, that matches any horizontal whitespace. This is a handy pattern when your regex can match across lines. Note `\s` matches line breaks, and this might result in unwelcome matches. Hence, all `\s` are replaced with `\h`.

Fifth, as the pattern will consume the `*/` line, and you want to start looking for a line not starting with `@` only right below that line, you need a *positive lookbehind*, a non-consuming pattern.

So, the grep command will look like

```sh
grep -zroP '(?m)/\*\*$\n?|^\h+\*\h.*$\n?|^\h+\*/$\n?|(?<=\*/\n)(?:\h+@.*\n)*\K.+\n?' test.txt
```

The `(?<=\*/\n)(?:\h+@.*\n)*\K.+\n?` alternatives does this:

- `(?<=\*/\n)` - finds the position that is immediately preceded with `*/` and a newline char
- `(?:\h+@.*\n)*` - matches and consumes any zero or more repetitions of

  - `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `@` - a `@` char
  - `.*\n` - the rest of the line with a newline (LF) char
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `.+` - the non-empty line
- `\n?` - an optional LF (line feed) char.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uryDMb/3).